# Many ways to create a Temporary file: what is the situation behind each method?

Tags: c++, winapi, temporary-files

My C++ winAPI application has a need to create a temporary file prior to uploading the file to a server. So I have searched ways to create a temporary file & found there are many ways to do this.

**Can you tell me:** For each of the following methods below, in which scenario am I supposed to use that method? And which method would best suite my needs?

Method 1:

```
// Using CreateFile()
CreateFile( "myfile.txt", GENERIC_ALL, ..., FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY, 0); // removed unecessary parameters
```

Method 2:

```
// I think that GetTempFileName also creates the file doesn't it? Not just generates a unique fileName?
//  Gets the temp path env string (no guarantee it's a valid path).
dwRetVal = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH,          // length of the buffer
                       lpTempPathBuffer); // buffer for path 

//  Generates a temporary file name. 
uRetVal = GetTempFileName(lpTempPathBuffer, // directory for tmp files
                          TEXT("DEMO"),     // temp file name prefix 
                          0,                // create unique name 
                          szTempFileName);  // buffer for name
```

Method 3:

```
// Create a file & use the flag DELETE_ON_CLOSE. So its a temporary file that will delete when the last HANDLE to it closes
HANDLE h_file = CreateFile( tmpfilename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, NULL );
```

*Why are there more than 1 way to create a temp file. And, for example, what is the situation where I would want to use, say, method 2 over method 1?*

Answer (score 6):

`FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` simply tells Windows not to bother writing the file contents to disk if there's enough cache, because the file is temporary and no other process will be using it.

`FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` means just what it says - when you close the file it will be deleted automatically. This guarantees that it will be temporary.

`GetTempFilename` creates a name for a temporary file, and guarantees that the filename hasn't been used previously.

You should use all 3 methods when creating a temporary file. None of them interferes with the others.

Comment: FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY attribute causes file systems to avoid writing data back to mass storage if sufficient cache memory is available. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#caching_behavior

Comment: @Sergius, thanks for the correction - I've edited it into the answer. I remembered that it had something to do with cache, but obviously botched the details. Great link by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For method #2 if you use 0 for the "unique ID" you actually need to call SetFileAttributes with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY to make the generated file temporary in the same sense as method #1 (otherwise it will be a normal ARCHIVE/NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED file.)

Use GetFileAttributes or GetFileInformationByHandle to see what attributes the file actually possesses.